# Application load balancer metrics present in the aws documentation not availaible in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, aws-application-load-balancer

While trying to work with few of the Cloudwatch metrics for Application load balancer , i could see few of the metrics defined in  the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html), aren't available in the AWS console. ClientTLSNegotiationErrorCount , DroppedInvalidHeaderRequestCount , HTTP_Redirect_Count  and RejectedConnectionCount being a few of them .

Is it something to do with the region as am using frankfurt or is it a documentation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all there if you keep in mind that:

> If there are no requests flowing through the load balancer or no data
> for a metric, the metric is not reported.

For example:

[image]

You can even find some of them, if they have been reported, in the CloudWatch Console.

[image]

[image]